# Are Variables passed by reference to libraries?

Tags: solidity

I understand from my reading that a library in solidity receives variables by reference and then updates directly the calling contract's variables.

Is it then correct to state then for all library calls the variables are passed by reference only and then local or state variables are updated in the calling contract by the library?

I assume the variable address is passed to the library for state variables, and for local variables, the memory address is passed. Is that correct?

Comment: Libraries are called by contracts using `delegatecall`. In fact, nothing is "passed" into the library. The library code runs as if it's contract code itself.